# How do you cure sensitivity in a dog

Tags: dogs, behavior

We have a 3 year old Chihuahua/Rat Terrier dog, he is so sensitive to noise, us pushing him not to do a movement. He is also sensitive about seeing other people or dogs on the street when taking him for a walk. He will bark like crazy inside at people or dogs, but get him out there with those people or dogs, he runs for the house. He is a very lovable dog and minds rather well. But don't know what to do about his sensitivity?